# Should the same source be cited repeatedly in a chapter?

Tags: citations, thesis, bachelor

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis on IT-Forensics. One of my first chapters is the explanation of of the basics of IT-Forensics, the procedures and its goals.

To do that, I am primarily referencing the forensics class I had in the previous semester, as well as a technical report on IT-Forensics from a different university.

Should I cite every claim with the same source repeatedly, or should I cite my sources in the beginning or end of the chapter once?

Comment: You should write in a way that your sources are clearly identifiable. You needn't repeat the same source every time, because sometimes the source will be clear. You must repeat the source when it is unclear. If in doubt, then cite.

Comment: @user2768 Should I mention it in any way, maybe in a footnote? Like that the following subsection is all referenced to `\cite{...}`?

Comment: the way you handle it really depends on the context. E.g., you might open with "This section recalls terminology from Stockinger~\cite{...}." Note that it is sometimes better to cite the original source of terminology, rather than citing lecture notes.